# Getting time in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, c

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int GetTime()
{

   struct timespec tsp;

   clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tsp);   //Call clock_gettime to fill tsp

   fprintf(stdout, "time=%d.%d\n", tsp.tv_sec, tsp.tv_nsec);

   fflush(stdout);

}
```

I am trying to compile the above code but it keeps throwing the error:

```
time.c: In function ‘GetTime’:
time.c:12:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘clock_gettime’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
time.c:12:18: error: ‘CLOCK_REALTIME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
time.c:12:18: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
time.c:14:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘__time_t’ [-Wformat]
time.c:14:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long int’ [-Wformat]
```

I have tried compiling with -lrt flag and -std=gnu99. Nothing works.

Comment: First thing `#include <time.h>`is missing.

Comment: Copy and paste error. Sorry

Comment: For me `#include <sys/time.h>` did not work only `#include <time.h>`

Comment: Yes. That was the error. COuld you please post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `#include <sys/time.h>` with `#include <time.h>`

and  `fprintf(stdout, "time=%d.%d\n", tsp.tv_sec, tsp.tv_nsec);` with

```
fprintf(stdout, "time=%d.%d\n", (int) tsp.tv_sec, (int) ttsp.tv_nsec);
```

Another good example: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1244004&p=7812845#post7812845